# URL Scheme Picking wrong value

Tags: ios, firebase, plist, firebase-dynamic-links, info.plist

I have set up firebase dynamic links and it's working fine in the dev environment, but it's not working in QA and Prod. `Bundle Identifier` in the plist is set to `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)` and when I check the package, the bundle identifier is correct for the dev/QA/Prod. I have also set one of the `URL Schemes` in the plist to `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)`.When I checked the package, the URL Schemes is picking the correct value for the dev environment, but it is assigning dev value for both the QA and Prod. What I'm doing wrong?

FYI: In the build settings -> Product Bundle Identifier -> Dev bundle identifier is set for both Debug and Release? How do I change the Release bundle ID to pick the value from `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)`? I tried to change the release bundle ID to `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)`, but jenkins is throwing error.

I have two questions:

1. How to pick the correct bundle ID in the plist `URL Schemes`
2. How to set the `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)` in the Build Settings -> Product Bundle Identifier -> Release?